# Check if two objects have a similar value and get value

Tags: javascript

Is there a solution to check in JavaScript if two objects have the same value and then get the value?

Here is some code for demonstration:

An Object in Array 1 (“generalData”):

```js
this.generalData = [
  {
    specificId: 210001,
    name: 'Test 1',
    optionsAvaiable: false,
    mode: 0,
  },
];
```

An Object in Array 2 (“selectedData”):

```js
this.selectedData = [
  {
    specificId: 210001,
    name: 'Test 1',
    optionsAvaiable: false,
    column: {
      disableHtmlEncode: true,
      allowSorting: false,
      allowResizing: true,
      allowFiltering: false,
      allowGrouping: false,
    },
    foreignKeyData: undefined,
    index: '0',
    mode: 0,
  },
];
```

I want to get the specific id so the *expected output is `210001`*

My current solution (messy):

```js
this.generalData.forEach((generalDataObj) => {
  this.selectedData.forEach((selectedDataObj) => {
    if (generalDataObj.specificId == selectedDataObj.specificId) {
      console.log(generalDataObj.specificId); // (210001)
    }
  });
});
```

Is there a cleaner solution to solve this?

Comment: Why not just `if (generalData.specificId == selectedData.specificId) { ...` I don't see the need to loop anything

Comment: The OP wrote that it's objects inside of arrays (hence the `forEach`). However it could be made more clear

Answer (score 0):

If you only want one result, you can use the [find](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/find) method.

```js
const generalData = [{ specificId: 2345 }, { specificId: 1234 }]
const selectedData = [{ specificId: 1234 }, { specificId: 876 }, { specificId: 675 }]

const result = generalData.find(a => selectedData.find(b => a.specificId === b.specificId))
console.log(result)
```

Comment: If there are multiple matches, they should all be output if possible (respectively combined into a new array). For example `[210001, 210003, 210009]`. Do you may know a way to do this?

Comment: @NicolasB. you can use a combination of [filter](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) and [some](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/some) for that

Comment: Could you maybe give me an example of what this might look like? :)